# Copying std::thread::spawn and Send behavior, but with a different trait and function

Tags: rust, closures, traits

I am learning Rust and have run into the following problem, which is not obvious to me.
I saw a std::thread::spawn in the library, looked at the implementation, and saw that some type requires an implementation of the Send trait to be able to send something to another thread.
I'm trying to replicate the behavior with my own function and my own trait, but the compiler successfully compiles the code without complaining that the trait is not implemented for my types.
What am I missing?

```rust
pub trait SomeTrait {
    fn bar(&self);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct StructWithoutTrait {
    _data: Box<i32>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct StructWithTrait {
    _data: Box<i32>
}

impl SomeTrait for StructWithTrait {
    fn bar(&self) {}
}

fn foo<F, T>(f: F) -> T
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: SomeTrait + 'static,
    T: SomeTrait + 'static
{
    f.bar();
    f()
}

impl<F, T> SomeTrait for F
where 
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    T: SomeTrait
{
    fn bar(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let without_trait = StructWithoutTrait { _data: Box::new(1) };
    let with_trait = StructWithTrait { _data: Box::new(2) };
    let x = std::rc::Rc::new(1);

    foo(move || {
        println!("{:?}", without_trait);
        println!("{:?}", x);
        with_trait
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Send` is [an `auto` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#auto-traits). Auto-traits are somewhat like compiler-implemented; the steps of determining whether a type `T` implements an auto trait `AutoTrait` are the following:

1. If there is an explicit `impl AutoTrait for T`, then `T` always impls `AutoTrait` (note that because [`Send` is an `unsafe trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Send.html) you need `unsafe impl Send for T`, but the general principle stays the same).
2. Otherwise, if there is a *negative impl* `impl !AutoTrait for T`, then `T` does not implement `AutoTrait`. Note that this is an error to have both positive and negative impl of the same trait for the same type.
3. Otherwise, if any of the fields of `T` does not implement `AutoTrait`, `T` does not implement it either. For example, if `T` is defined as `struct T(U);`, and there's `impl !AutoTrait for U`, then `T` does not implement `AutoTrait`.
4. Otherwise, `T` implements `AutoTrait`.

Both auto traits and negative impls are highly unstable features, and not intended to use as of now outside of the standard library. If you *really* want, you can, although because the compiler must be able to implement the trait automatically, it cannot contain any associated item (methods, associated types, associated consts). If you remove the `bar()` method, this is how your code will look like:

```rust
#![feature(auto_traits, negative_impls)]

pub auto trait SomeTrait {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct StructWithoutTrait {
    _data: Box<i32>
}

impl !SomeTrait for StructWithoutTrait {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct StructWithTrait {
    _data: Box<i32>
}

fn foo<F, T>(f: F) -> T
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: SomeTrait + 'static,
    T: SomeTrait + 'static
{
    f()
}
fn main() {
    let without_trait = StructWithoutTrait { _data: Box::new(1) };
    let with_trait = StructWithTrait { _data: Box::new(2) };
    let x = std::rc::Rc::new(1);

    foo(move || {
        println!("{:?}", without_trait);
        println!("{:?}", x);
        with_trait
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f978d68e16cded207d2332f1434a523).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that is compiler behaviour:

> A closure is Send if all variables captured by non-unique immutable reference are Sync, and all values captured by unique immutable or mutable reference, copy, or move are Send.

~ https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html

It is therefore not something you can really implement right now with how closure types are completely untransparent

Answer (score 0):

Currently `Send` is handled specially by the the compiler. Quoting from [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/marker/trait.Send.html):

> This trait is automatically implemented when the compiler determines it’s appropriate.

There are [plans](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0019-opt-in-builtin-traits.md) to move the implementation fully into the standard library ([tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/13231)), which should make it possible to have similar user-defined marker traits. There is a chance that when this feature gets stabilized you might be able to write:

```
auto trait SomeTrait {}

struct StructWithTrait {}

struct StructWithoutTrait {}
impl !SomeTrait for StructWithoutTrait {}
```

and get a behaviour similar to `Send`.